# MySQL nested tables record numbering

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I have a MySQL problem similar to the following example.

- There are two tables with names of people, identified by their passport numbers The first table has PARENTS.
- The second table has CHILDREN, linked to their parent passport ID (I only take in account one parent -either father/mother- per family).
- A lower a passport ID value means a younger person (so, the youngest parent has the lowest ID; and the first child born in a family has the lowest ID among children in that family)

**EXAMPLE TABLES:**

**PARENTS**

```
PassportID – ParentNAME

098765432 – Kate
012345678 – John
111222333 – Mary
```

**CHILDREN**

```
PassportID – ChildNAME – ParentID

211222333 – Peter – 111222333
222333444 – Gabriel – 012345678
222222222 – Lara – 111222333
233333333 – Angela – 012345678
244444444 – Philip – 012345678
255555555 – Michael – 111222333
277777777 – Betty – 098765432
266666666 – Eleanor – 098765432
299999999 – Amanda – 111222333
288888888 – Robert – 111222333
```

I know how to join and sort these tables, using the original IDs:

<s>http:sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98b5a/1/0</s>

For some reason SQLfiddle started to fail, so I reproduced the example in this other cool MySQL tester:
http://rextester.com/EYIX74197

But I want to show simple growing numbers, instead of showing the original IDs. So, the question is:

How can I make a select from those two tables and get a list of all these people with a couple of **autonumbering columns which show the 1-based age rank of the people**, in this way:

- The oldest parent will have rank = 1. The next one, rank = 2, and so
  on
- And the **oldest child in EACH family will have rank = 1**, the next
  one 2, and so on.

**EXAMPLE RESULT:**

```
ParentAgeRANK - ParentNAME – ChildBornRANK – ChildNAME

1 – John – 1 – Gabriel
1 – John – 2 – Angela
1 – John – 3 – Philip
2 – Kate – 1 – Eleanor
2 – Kate – 2 – Betty
3 – Mary – 1 – Peter
3 – Mary – 2 – Lara
3 – Mary – 3 – Michael
3 – Mary – 4 – Robert
3 – Mary – 5 – Amanda
```

I guess I would need to use a couple of mysql variables, @ParentAgeRank and @ChildBornRank, set their original value as 0, and then sum 1 for each row but only when the parent id changes (in the first case) or the child ID changes (in the second one). But also, the @ChildBornRank has to be reset to 0 when the parent id changes.
I would know how to do this using a PHP script which could evaluate PassportID and increment Ranks using PHP variables.

But in this case I am forced to get the ranked list using pure MySQL statements.

Is this idea even possible? How to take care of resetting one variable when the other changes its value?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions

**EDITs:**

Although my example has just 10 rows, **this is intended to be run from two tables with about 100 thousand records** each one.

The 1st solution provided by @Parfait indeed works with a few rows; but when I try it in the real world, my server hangs.

The 2nd solution by @Parfait did return a "disk full" error message, so I guess it was something related to the 1st comment in this page (too many joins and group by statements): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/full-disk.html

Comment: Your variable idea will be more efficient than the first (and so far only) solution provided below

Comment: Thanks for your opinion @Strawberry .  But any ideas on how to take care of variable changes and resets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @prev = x.parent_id THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END parentrank 
     , x.parentname
     , CASE WHEN @prev = x.parent_id THEN @j:=@j+1 ELSE @j:=1 END childrank
     , x.childname
     , @prev:=parent_id
  FROM ( SELECT p.passportid parent_id
            , p.parentname
            , c.passportid child_id
            , c.childname
         FROM parents p
         JOIN children c
           ON c.parentid = p.passportid
       ) x
  JOIN ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0,@j:=0) vars
 ORDER 
    BY x.parent_id
     , x.child_id;
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| parentrank | parentname | childrank | childname | @prev:=parent_id |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
|          1 | John       |         1 | Gabriel   |         12345678 |
|          1 | John       |         2 | Angela    |         12345678 |
|          1 | John       |         3 | Philip    |         12345678 |
|          2 | Kate       |         1 | Eleanor   |         98765432 |
|          2 | Kate       |         2 | Betty     |         98765432 |
|          3 | Mary       |         1 | Peter     |        111222333 |
|          3 | Mary       |         2 | Lara      |        111222333 |
|          3 | Mary       |         3 | Michael   |        111222333 |
|          3 | Mary       |         4 | Robert    |        111222333 |
|          3 | Mary       |         5 | Amanda    |        111222333 |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Great. This seems to work at least with my simple table examples. Still haven't had the time to try it with my big tables. To be honest, by the time you posted it I had already solved my problem in a similar way, and got busy including those data in the report I am working on. When I finish I will post my solution if it is somehow different, and mark yours as the good one if it is faster, of course.   Thanks a lot !!

Comment: I hope you will forgive my scepticism as to the veracity of that comment.

Comment: LOL.  Which part of my comment you meant?  No more research. Strawberry solution does the job in less than 2 seconds so it completely beats @Parfait solution.  I had done more or less the same as Strawberry but she/he posted it here before. The only difference is the **CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END** syntax. I used **IF (,,)** instead.  Also, I **SET** initial variable values before the SELECT statement, instead of setting them using JOIN.   But in essence, it is the same solution since the query, counters and comparisons work the same way.   Thanks a lot to both of you!!

Comment: Just for reference, I posted my implementation below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44745131/710788

Answer (score 1):

Consider correlated count subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM Parents sub
     WHERE sub.PassportID <= p.PassportID) AS ParentRANK,

    p.PassportID As ParentID, p.ParentNAME, 

    (SELECT Count(*) FROM Children sub
     WHERE sub.PassportID <= c.PassportID
     AND sub.ParentID = c.ParentID) AS ChildRANK,

    c.PassPortID As ChildID, c.ChildNAME    

FROM Parents p 
INNER JOIN Children c 
  ON p.PassportID = c.ParentID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98b5a/7)

---

Alternative using `JOIN` tables and `COUNT(DISTINCT ...))` in an aggregate query for ranking:

```
SELECT 
       Count(DISTINCT subP.PassportID) AS ParentRANK,
       p.PassportID As ParentID, p.ParentNAME,        
       Count(DISTINCT subC.PassportID) AS ChildRANK,        
       C.PassPortID As ChildID, c.ChildNAME

FROM Parents p 
INNER JOIN Children c 
  ON p.PassportID = c.ParentID

LEFT JOIN Parents subP
  ON subP.PassportID <= p.PassportID

LEFT JOIN Children subC   
  ON subC.PassportID <= c.PassportID
  AND subC.ParentID = c.ParentID

GROUP BY p.PassportID, p.ParentName, c.PassportID, c.ChildName
ORDER BY 1,4
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98b5a/13)

Comment: Hi.  Very good. Thank you SO MUCH.    It works simply perfect with my example table.   The problem is that my real tables are much bigger (my server has been running the query for 10 minutes now and still no results). I edited my original answer. Could you suggest an improvement that consumes less resources?

Comment: See updated alternative version using `JOIN` tables. Let me know if this is more efficient.

Comment: I couldn't run your second SQL fiddle example, @Parfait . It might be a sqlfiddle bug, but the page does not load in my browser.
In any case: I tried to adapt your query to my real database, and SQL server ran out of memory. 
So I guess this query was less efficient than the previous one  ;)
Thanks anyway

Comment: this is what I got with about 70000 parents and 82000 children in my tables: SOLUTION 1: 0 rows affected, 81,793 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 1,457.703 sec. (+ 1,614.906 sec. network) ; SOLUTION 2: run out of disk space   ...    So the only solution which worked took about 50 minutes to finish.  Hopefully someone can beat this ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is essentialy the same way to do it provided by @Strawberry above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44578041/710788

I just put my version here to better understand the differences I mentioned:

```
SET @prank=0, @crank=1, @curp=0, @curc=0;

SELECT 
  if(o.Passportid<>@curp, @prank:=@prank+1, @prank) as 'ParentRANK', 
  o.ParentName,
  if(o.Passportid<>@curp, @crank:=1, @crank:=@crank+1) as 'ChildRANK', 
  o.ChildName, 
  if(o.Passportid<>@curp, @curp:=o.Passportid, @curp) as 'current_P' 
FROM (
  SELECT p.Passportid,p.ParentNAME, c.PassportID as childID,c.ChildNAME,c.ParentID 
  FROM parents AS p INNER JOIN children as c on p.PassportID=c.ParentID 
  ORDER BY p.PASSPORTID,c.PassportID
) AS o;
```

Speed comparison with 553003 parents and 1106983 children:

**Solution above**

0 rows affected, 1,106,983 rows found. Duration for 3 queries: 7.020 sec.

**Solution by @Strawberry**

0 rows affected, 1,106,983 rows found. Duration for 1 query: 6.489 sec.

Note: these are many more rows than I originally said I needed to process. I just added them to better test speed differences.